# Understanding ANTLR/EBNF parentheses

Tags: antlr, antlr4, parentheses, bnf, ebnf

The [ANTLR Reference Guide](http://lms.ui.ac.ir/public/group/90/59/01/15738_ce57.pdf) says about parentheses as follows:

[image]

On the other hand, I have the following grammar:

```
fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

WORD                : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGIT )+;
```

If I run the string "asd90", it will be matched as a WORD as below:

```
>java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Myg myg -tokens
asd90
[@0,0:4='asd90',<WORD>,1:0]
[@1,5:6='\r\n',<NEWLINE>,1:5]
[@2,7:6='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

This causes me to be confused as I would expect "asd90" to not be matched since in my grammar, LOWERCASE and DIGIT are 2 different subrules, so i would have expected it to be not matched as "WORD".

In other terms it's like saying that "intvoid" would work as a return type where clearly it would not.

Comment: `LOWERCASE` and `DIGIT` are not 2 different subrules, they're fragments of one particular rule (more precisely token) `WORD`. In simple words this would sound like: "`WORD` may contain either lower case characters, or upper case characters or digits". That's what "asd90" is about. As to `intvoid` - it's not the same as `int void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to miss the loop operator in your consideration. The lexer rule `WORD` can match a **sequence** of any `LOWERCASE`, `UPPERCASE` and `DIGIT`, which means it is totally valid to match `asd90` by using 5 runs of that loop (matching the lower case rule 3 times and the digits rule twice).

The example from the book has no loop, so it can only match once, either a type or `void`.

A few more details: fragment rules are kinda private rules (and in fact in older ANLTR versions there was the keyword `private`, which later was renamed to `fragment`). However, they are not available in the parser and do not appear in the list of lexer rules. Your `WORD` rule is stored in the ATN like so:

[image]

which shows that the 3 fragment rules are called like any other rule.

But there's another difference (and that's what Pavel mentions). Fragment lexer rules are handled a bit differently when it comes to ambiquity resolution.

Normally the resolution is like this: The rule which matches the longest input wins. If two rules match the same input then the one which comes first in the grammar wins. This holds true for both parser and lexer rules. However, not for fragment rules. Even if a fragment rule that matches the same input as another (non-fragment) rule appears first in the grammar, the non-fragment rule still wins.

You can prove that by changing your grammar a bit:

```
grammar Example;

start: WORD;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z]+ ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z]+ ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9]+ ;
WORD: (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGIT )+;
```

This gives you these tokens:

[image]

With the input `abc` you will still get `WORD` as matched token, even though `LOWERCASE` comes first in the grammar. Now remove the fragment keyword and you will see that `LOWERCASE` is matched:

```
Parser error (1, 1): mismatched input 'abc' expecting WORD

Tokens:
[@0,0:2='abc',<2>,1:0]
[@1,4:3='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]

Parse Tree:
start (
  <Error>"abc"
)
```

which leads to a syntax error, because a `WORD` was expected. The token list becomes then:

[image]

However, even if you remove all fragment keywords, you will still get `WORD` for input like `abc90`, because that rules matches more than any of the invidiual lexer rules before it.

Comment: The loop operator is not the point, even if i added a loop operator in the book example, it could then match 'voidvoid' but not 'intvoid' where in the case of the WORD i could mix any of the sub fragment. I think the answer in in the comment from @Pavel Smirnov above. I compared 2 different things, in the book case it's sub rule in the parser and it's evaluated in isolation where in the case of the fragment it's like inlining fragment into a single "rule".

Comment: I guess you are missunderstanding how "+" works. It seems to me you are reading it like "apply the preceding parsing and if it matches apply its **match** over and over". That is not how "+" works. What it does is "apply the preceding **parsing** and while it matches reaply the **parsing** over and over"

Comment: First thx for the further explanations. So if i added a '+' in the book example, 'intvoid" woudl be a valid match?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. And it could even be something like `int void` because that `returnType` rule is a parser rule and it will also accept input which is separated by hidden tokens (like the skipped whitespaces).